# Outlook Interop - Read Calendars And Check for Private Appointments

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar

So I'm working on an app that will be able to read the outlook calendars for a set of individuals and build an itinerary for them.  I've got it pretty much working except that when I scrape a user's calendar, I'm not getting any information on the events they have marked as private.

Let me make it clear that I'm not trying to peer into a user's calendar and read their darkest secret appointment titles, but I would still like to be able to show that this person is unavailable during that time.  For example in Outlook proper it just shows as "Private Appointment" - which is exactly what I want to be able to do in my app.

Here's the code I've got for scraping the user's calendar:

```
    private Calendar CreateCalendar(String User_Name, String Initials, DateTime Week)
    {
        string filter = "[Start] >= '"
            + Week.ToString("g")
            + "' AND [End] <= '"
            + Week.AddDays(7).ToString("g") + "'";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = App.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        //Resolve the person whose calendar We're trying to read.
        Outlook.Recipient rm = App.Session.CreateRecipient(User_Name);
        if (rm.Resolve())
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Folder calFolder = App.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(rm, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;
                Outlook.Items CalItems = calFolder.Items;
                CalItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
                CalItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
                //Search for Items within the pre-defined time range.

                Outlook.Items restrictItems = CalItems.Restrict(filter);
                if (restrictItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Print("No Items Found");
                    return new Calendar(User_Name, Initials);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Create our internal representation of their calendar, for use elsewhere.
                    Calendar cal = new Calendar(User_Name, Initials);
                    Outlook.AppointmentItem i = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)restrictItems.GetFirst();

                    do
                    {
                        cal.AddAppointment(i.Subject, i.Start, i.End);
                        i = restrictItems.GetNext();
                    } while (i != null);

                    App = null;
                    mapiNamespace = null;
                    return cal;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App = null;
                mapiNamespace = null;
                throw new AccessViolationException(User_Name + " was resolved but could not access their calendar.  Have they set you up as a delegate?", ex);
            }
        }
        else
            throw new AccessViolationException("The name " + User_Name + " was not resolved, make sure their name in the RM List is spelled correctly. If you can enter their name as a recipient in an outlook mail message and it resolves correctly when you click 'Check Names', then it should work!");
    }
```

I'm not sure if private events are contained in the same "Folder" in outlook's data structures, so maybe I'm just not looking in the right spot?

I've been having trouble googling this because "private" is a reserved word in C# that basically hits on every single post with code and a function declaration in it.  Hopefully you guys will be more helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: It could be a problem with your search filter - what's the complete text of a particular query?  Try it without the search - you should get everything in their Calendar

Comment: Here's the text of the Search Filter: `"[Start] >= '2/1/2016 12:00 AM' AND [End] <= '2/8/2016 12:00 AM'"`  I know there is at least one "Private" event within this range, and I'm getting both of the other appointments on either side of it.

Comment: Has the delegatee been given the right to view private items?  That's an explicit setting

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting a 4 year old question, but I'm trying to do this exact same thing. Even having the same problems Googling a solution due to the "private" keyword. Did you ever end up finding a solution?

Comment: It took me a while to even remember what project this was from, but I seem to recall that after discussing it with my manager we just decided not to include the private appointments. Sorry, wish I had a better answer for you!  If you do find a solution I'd be curious to know what it is.

Comment: Ended with a workaround using Recipient.FreeBusy, parsing out non-private entries from the Free/Busy data to get where private appointments exist. This has its own flaws as just seeing a block of free/busy information doesn't distinguish multiple concurrent appointments or back-to-back appointments vs. one long appointment, plus they can be hidden by concurrent non-private appointments and need the time frame constrained since they can't just be iterated. While this was enough for my particular purpose, it's far from ideal in the general case.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me though, especially on such an old question. Greatly appreciated.